# Johnson-Nyquist noise for resistive element with temperature gradient

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, noise

In Nyquist's 1928 paper, [Thermal agitation of electric charge in conductors](http://phys.csuchico.edu/ayars/300B/handouts/Nyquist.pdf), the voltage noise for a resistor is derived assuming a circuit in thermal equilibrium and one temperature.

How does the thermal noise of a resistor change when there is a temperature gradient? For example, a circuit that has different resistors at extremely different temperatures, or one long resistive element that has a temperature gradient across the whole thing?

Nyquist looks at a circuit like this one

[image]

where both $R1$ and $R2$ are at the same temperature $T$. Each noisy resistor is modeled as a noisless resistor in series with a noise source so that they can be considered one at a time.

Nyquist uses the fact that the circuit is in thermal equilibrium twice in his derivation: once to argue that the power from $R1$ to $R2$ is equal to the power from $R2$ to $R1$, and once to use the equipartition theorem and assign an energy $k_BT/2$ to each degree of freedom of each mode in a transmission line between the two resistors.

If the temperature of the resistors are different, can you really say that the power from each is the same? If $R1$ and $R2$ are at different temperatures and not at thermal equilibrium, then it seems like you can't use the equipartition theorem and the whole derivation falls apart. Is there a different way to treat the case of resistors at different temperatures?

Comment: Would it be more proper to show the whole derivation and then ask the question about it? I'm just worried it would make for a very long question.

Answer (score 1):

"a circuit that has different resistors at extremely different temperatures" -- Each resistor independently puts out its own noise related to its own temperature.

"one long resistive element that has a temperature gradient across the whole thing" -- That's actually the same thing again. Treat it as a large number N of resistors in series, each with resistance of R/N, and each with a slightly different temperature.

UPDATE: I think you misunderstand the role that thermal equilibrium plays in the derivation. Nyquist is trying to answer the question "What is the noise created by a resistor at temperature T?" Then he proposes a *thought experiment*, a particular circumstance in which the answer to the question is especially obvious. But nevertheless the answer is general. This kind of thing, where you derive a general principle using a specific thought experiment, is common in physics derivations.

The noise voltage created by a resistor is obviously independent of what else is in the circuit, or what temperature that other stuff has. (The *consequences* of the voltage of course does depend on the whole circuit via Kirchhoff's laws.) Therefore the conclusions of Nyquist's thought experiment can be applied in any other circumstance.

Comment: Steve, Thanks for the answer. I'm concerned because the derivation requires thermal equilibrium at a fixed temperature, and I'm not sure that it's clear that you can apply it to a different case. Can you maybe provide an argument for why it is still applicable?

Comment: *"The noise voltage created by a resistor is obviously independent of what else is in the circuit, or what temperature that other stuff has."* In my opinion, that is not entirely obvious as it makes the assumption that the noise and the temperature are related in a one-to-one way. It can be argued (and shown experimentally) that the noise is only a function of temperature and resistance, but this is not entirely obvious.